# validation of special characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i want to put validation in ruby on rails that my username should not contain special characters like !@#$%^*()_-+=/<>?:'";.
Please tell me how can i implement it in my code.

Answer (score 3):

Using your model [validates_format_of](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M001401) as suggested by @Voyta

I am adding a regular expression in my example though :

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /\A[a-zA-Z]+([a-zA-Z]|\d)*\Z/
```

Comment: How might you amended this to allow spaces as would be the case for something like 'full name'?

Answer (score 1):

Use [validates_format_of](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of) (see comments there for regex examples):

```
validates_format_of :username, :with => /\Ayour_regex_here\Z/i
```